# How can I retrieve the metrics from my Solr server using SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj

We are running Solr 8.4 and SolrJ 8.4. I can successfully retrieve about 18K lines of metrics using curl: `curl 'http://localhost:1080/MySolr/admin/metrics'`. How can I retrieve the same metrics using SolrJ?

I was unable to find any information in either the Solr or SolrJ documentation about this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use `query.setParam(CommonParams.QT, "/admin/metrics");` to give a custom query path if the url is actually beneath a core name.

Comment: @MatsLindh
Thanks, that worked. Do you want to make it an answer and I will mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make explicit use of the `CommonParams.QT` parameter to change the query path into any value.

```
query.setParam(CommonParams.QT, "/admin/metrics");
```

This lets you make a custom query to a path under a specific core name.